# How to get SPWebApplication from SPWeb?

Tags: c#, sharepoint-2010, spweb

So I'm inside a **web** scroped feature (`properties.Feature.Parent` = `SPWeb`).

How do I get the `SPWebApplication` from this `SPWeb`?

I tried:

```
SPWebApplication webApp = (SPWebApplication)properties.Feature.Parent;
```

But of course I get an exception because I cannot cast the `SPWeb` object as an `SPWebApplication`.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

You can try:

```
SPWeb web = properties.Feature.Parent as SPWeb;
SPWebApplication webApp = web.Site.WebApplication;
```

Comment: You need following namespace: Microsoft.SharePoint.Administration